# Cannot index with multidimensional key

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to filter out all row having value "Completely Disbursed" in column "applicationstatus_x".

```
df = df.loc[df.applicationstatus_x == 'Complete Disbursed']
df.shape
```

> ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

I can see, there's currently 2x applicationstatus_x and applicationstatus_y, created probably when I was joining DFs.
I tried to get an index of applicationstatus_x and drop it but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a different index for `df` and `df2`, so if `len(df) == len(df2)`

```
df2 = df2.loc[(df.applicationstatus_x == 'Complete Disbursed').values]
```

Comment: Sorry, that's typo xD